# Bind variable to this

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, plugins

I'm creating a simple jQuery plugin and am having trouble making it modular.

For example:

```
$.fn.testMethod = function(option1, option2) {
    var something1 = option1;
    var something2 = option2;
};
```

My problem starts to occur when I have more than one element using this method. For example:

```
$('.element1').testMethod(1, 2);
$('.element2').testMethod(3, 4);
```

The second element ends up using the variable of the first later down the line if I'm changing stuff around. What would be a better way of doing this and locking the variables to the specific element they're being used with? If this is too vague, I can paste in my full code but it is a bit complex.

Comment: Please re-word the question title - it doesn't describe the problem at all.

Comment: Not sure how else I'd word the question, sorry.

Comment: Please include the relevant code that actually shows the problem. Right now every call has their own options.

Comment: Will include the code when I get home, unfortunately I'm currently at work. Didn't think this question with get a response so quickly. To sort of explain what I am doing: I am creating an animation plugin. Each element has a currentFrame variable and a currentLoop variable. Everything works great and loops correctly with one element, but adding another element causes the shorter animation to stop prematurely. I'm almost positive this is caused by the shorter animation calling the currentFrame or currentLoop variable and getting it in the context of the longer animation, causing it to stop.

Answer (score 1):

When working with jQuery plugins, you generally want to do an `each` loop and return the collection.

That also means you can't use just simple variables, but that's where jQuery's `data` comes in handy.

```
$.fn.testMethod = function(option1, option2) {

    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).data('something1', option1);
        $(this).data('something2', option2);

        // do stuff

        var something =  $(this).data('something1'); // etc
    });

};
```

On the other hand, the arguments and variables inside the function will be unique to each function call, so there's no way the second call to the function would use the variables from the first call unless you're doing something else strange.

Comment: This seems like it could work, I will definitely test it out and see if it works in my situation.

Comment: @glitchedbits - It's a very general answer, I have no idea how you're using those variables, but using `data` lets you work with data on an per-element basis in a much better way.

Comment: @adeneo Comment removed.

Comment: I'm almost positive using data binding will work in my instance, unfortunately I won't be able to test it until I get off work.